# Assigning a value to a letter to use in an equation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am writing an application in JavaScript that handles a series of simple equations. It's mainly additions involving numbers from 0 to 10, but the letter X needs to be usable as well: counting as the number 10. This is part of what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateround() {
        document.form.round01.value = (document.form.arrow01.value -0) + (document.form.arrow02.value -0) + (document.form.arrow03.value -0);
    }
</script>
<body>
    <center>
            <form name="form">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input name="arrow01" style="width: 30px;" onChange="updateround()"></td>
                        <td><input name="arrow02" style="width: 30px;" onChange="updateround()"></td>
                        <td><input name="arrow03" style="width: 30px;" onChange="updateround()"></td>
                        <td><input name="round01" style="width: 30px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
    </center>
</body>
```

If you run this you get 4 input fields: if you write numbers in the first three and click somewhere else they add up in the fourth field.

What I am looking for is how to make it so that if you enter the letter X into one of the first three fields the application uses it as 10 in the equation. For example, if you enter X, 9 and 9 in the first three fields you get 28 in the fourth, if you enter X, X and 6 you get 26 and so on. Also, where do I put this code in the application?

May thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a small extra function to add:

```
function val_or_x_from_object(obj) {
    if (obj.value == "x" || obj.value == "X") {
        return 10;  
    }
    else {
        val = parseFloat(obj.value);
        return (isNaN(val)? 0 : val);
    }
}

function updateround() {
        document.form.round01.value = val_or_x_from_object(document.form.arrow01) + 
           val_or_x_from_object(document.form.arrow02) + 
            val_or_x_from_object(document.form.arrow03);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a base-eleven-system, you can use `parseInt` with radix 11. Only it expects `a`/`A` instead of `X`, so you will need to use a replace before:

```
parseInt(document.form.arrow01.value.replace(/x/gi, "a"), 11)
```

If you would want to use radix 11 for output as well, you can use `toString` and again the replace:

```
result.toString(11).replace(/a/gi, "X");
```